# Can not able to print value of a object

Tags: javascript

in javscript

I can't able to fetch value from a object.

When printing whole object is printing. But, when I am trying to access only 1 field it is showing error

```
function add_new_row()
{
  let gg = 
  {
    "1st_col" : '99',
    "2nd_col" : '88',
    "3rd_col" : ['77', '66'],
    "4th_col" : '55',
  }
  console.log(gg); //{1st_col: "99", 2nd_col: "88", 3rd_col: Array(2), 4th_col: "55"}
  console.log(gg.1st_col); //Error here

  //this is the line where I called this function in button HTML
}
```

The error that is thrown is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: add_new_row is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index2.html:120)
    onclick @ index2.html:120
```

Comment: Given your code, it is impossible for `console.log(gg.1st_col);` to throw `Uncaught ReferenceError: add_new_row is not defined`.

Comment: In this particular case, you can use brackets to access the property, like: `console.log(gg["1st_col"]);` You can check the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation) for valid identificators when using dot notation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not access via dot notation if the fields name starts with a number. It's a convention rule defined in lexical analysis of javascript compiler for vars naming.

This is valid:

```
gg.first_col
gg._1st_col
gg.a1st_col
```

If you use the bracket notation is valid to refer to these fields in that way:

```
gg["1st_col"]
```

--- edit ---

These are the basic rules for defining variable names in javascript:

- Names should begin with lowercase string.
- Names cannot contain symbols or begin with symbols.
- Names cannot begin with a number.
- Names can contain a mix of uppercase strings, lowercase strings, and numbers.

Source: https://scotch.io/courses/10-need-to-know-javascript-concepts/declaring-javascript-variables-var-let-and-const

Comment: Intresting. We need to study documentation to know all these? Or is there any other way to know this type of rules?

Comment: Yes, you can investigate more about it in the documentation. These are the basic rules for defining variable names:

1. Names should begin with lowercase string.
2. Names cannot contain symbols or begin with symbols.
3. Names cannot begin with a number.
4. Names can contain a mix of uppercase strings, lowercase strings, and numbers.